# How do i dynamically adjust pacing in Jmeter based on the response times

Tags: jmeter

I want pacing to change dynamically based on iteration length . 
For ex: 
Consider max iteration length say x sec

If iteration takes n sec (n < x) , then pacing should x - n sec.
If iteration takes n sec (n >= x) , then pacing should be 0 sec.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) scripting and [JSR223 Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)

- [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to record iteration start time
- your
- requests
- here
- [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) sampler to implement pacing

  - [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) - to record iteration end time and calculate Test Action "sleep" time

More information: [How to Easily Implement Pacing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-easily-implement-pacing-jmeter)